# How to limit EditText lines to 1 by coding (ignoring enter)?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to ignore the enter key, but i do not want to use onKeyDown() function.

There is a way to do this in xml:
1. android:maxLines = "1"
2. android:lines = "1"
3. android:singleLine = "true"

I actually want to do the last one by coding. Does anyone know how to do that?

```
for (int i=0; i<numClass; i++) {

        temp_ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        temp_ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        temp1 = new EditText(this);
        InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
        FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(12);
        temp1.setFilters(FilterArray);  // set edit text length to max 12
        temp1.setHint("  class name  ");
        temp1.setSingleLine(true);

        temp_ll.addView(temp1);
        frame.addView(temp_ll);
    }

    ll.addView(frame);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i tried:

```
public class Next extends Activity{
    LinearLayout lay;
    LinearLayout temp_ll;
    EditText temp1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.next);
    lay=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lay);



         temp_ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        temp_ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        temp1 = new EditText(this);
        InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
        FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(12);
        temp1.setFilters(FilterArray);  // set edit text length to max 12
        temp1.setHint("  class name  ");
        temp1.setSingleLine(true);

        temp_ll.addView(temp1);



    lay.addView(temp_ll);



}
}
```

Xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That does not work. It is like i want to ignore the enter key.

Comment: thats not possible by setting this property to true the edittext doesnot respond to enter key.. can you show your code...

Comment: i added that part for you, look at original posting

Answer (score 0):

try using `setSingleLine` as:

```
EditText editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editv);

editText.setSingleLine(true);
```

Comment: that did not work. if a press "enter" i still go to the next line.